# Show that every infinite recursive set has both a nonrecursive r.e. subset and a non-r.e. subset

Tags: computability, sets

My attempt to solve this:

If $\mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary infinite recursive set then the members of $\mathcal{A}$ can be ordered in ascending order. We can do bijection between $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{A}$.

Halting problem is $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ and therefore it's also $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$. And the same can be said about $\bar{\mathcal{K}}$.

Is my solution correct? Are there any "better" solutions to this problem?

Comment: why does it follow that $K \subset A$??  Indeed, you can find a bijection, but it may not be a subset.

Comment: If I order the members of $\mathcal{A}$ and enumerate them such that lowest possible member of $\mathcal{A}$ is 0, next one is 1, next one is 2, etc. I have - because the $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite - a set of natural numbers. Let the bijecting function is $f$. So if $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ then I use the $f$ to get the number in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: You're claiming that $\mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ and also $\overline{\mathcal{K}}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$.  That cannot be true unless $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am claiming that $\mathcal{A}$ has as many elements as $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: @Gordon That's not what you wrote. The sentence beginning "Halting problem is" means what I said it means.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see. How do I formally and correctly write what I **meant** to say? That because there are as many elements in $\mathcal{A}$ as there are in $\mathcal{N}$ we can pick elements from $\mathcal{A}$ whose bijection to $\mathcal{N}$ is an index of a program in $\mathcal{K}$.

Comment: What about: Since $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ then $f(\mathcal{K})\subseteq\mathcal{A}$, where $f$ is a bijection function.

Comment: Check http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1793/683 for some hints. Also, I have a feeling that this question has already been asked before.

Comment: @Gordon I see what you mean, now. You probably want to say something like, "Let $\mathcal{K} = \{k_1, k_2, \dots\}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{a_1, a_2, \dots\}$.  Then consider the set $\{a_{k_1}, a_{k_2}, \dots\}$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, precisely! Would that work? Is it a sufficient proof? Would the set $\{a_{k_1},a_{k_2},...\}$ be r.e. (or non-r.e. in case of $\bar{\mathcal{K}}$?

Comment: @Gordon Yes, the set would be r.e./co-r.e. in the two cases. You just need to prove it and you have your answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In order to prove it's r.e. I could argue that if $\mathcal{K_\mathcal{A}}=\{a_{k_1},a_{k_2},...\}$ was recursive the characteristic function for $\mathcal{K}$ would be $\chi_\mathcal{K}=\chi_{\mathcal{K_\mathcal{A}}}\circ f$, where $f$ is a bijection function and $\chi_{\mathcal{K_\mathcal{A}}}$ is a characteristic function for $\mathcal{K_\mathcal{A}}$ which we know exists from our assumption that $\mathcal{K_\mathcal{A}}$ is recursive. This is however contradiction, because we know that $\mathcal{K}$ is not recursive.